# how to display the dynamically created chart generated by a java program using database, in a jsp page

Tags: image, jsp, dynamic, jfreechart

I am generating a line chart using the datas from database and I have to pass this generated chart to a jsp page. Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are number of solutions, depending on the level of interactivity you require. Also you have not specified how you generate the chart.

Possibly the best solution would be to use Adobe flash so that you have best interactivity.

If static chart is just fine, then you can generate a png / gif file and insert the link for its generation as a source for html IMG.

Comment: Thanks jiri.i am using jfreechart to generate a line chart.This chart is generated by using the datas stored from the database.once the chart is created i need to display the chart which is created dynamically into a web page through servlet.I tried saving the chart as an png image under a webcontent,and i and i have specified the location in img src path.But the chart is not displayed in the jsp page.

Comment: http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/07/10/displaying-dynamic-charts-in-a-jsp-page-jfreechart/

Comment: hi all..now i am able to display image in servlet now i want the image to be written directly in jsp.